# Ionic 2 - How to set nextpage dynamically based on the card you clicked?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an page where I have cards like this:

```
<ion-card *ngIf="oefening1" (click)="test($event)" id="lagerugklacht" class="lagerugklacht">
<img src="assets/img/lagerugklacht.jpg"/>
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-card-title>{{ oefening1 }}</ion-card-title>
  <p>Setjes: {{ set1 }}</p>
  <p>Herhalingen: {{ rep1 }}</p>
</ion-card-content>
```

```
<ion-card *ngIf="oefening2" (click)="test()">
    <img src="assets/img/nekklacht.jpg"/>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>{{ oefening2 }}</ion-card-title>
      <p>Setjes: {{ set2 }}</p>
      <p>Herhalingen: {{ rep2 }}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

What I want to do is when I click one of those cards I will be redirected to an page where the video url is set dynamically, based on the card you clicked.

So what I tried is to pick up the `id="lagerugklacht"` and based on that `NavParam` I want to set the video url. But it seems it doesn't pick up the parent id in my console.log. Maybe there is a proper way of doing this?

Here is an example of my `click event`

```
 test(event){
   console.log(event);
   console.log(event.srcElement.attributes.id);
   var idAttr = event.srcElement.attributes.id;
   var value = idAttr.nodeValue;
   console.log(value);
  // this.navCtrl.push(ExercisePage);
}
```

Maybe it is possible to pass `{{ oefening1 }}` with the click event?

Comment: do you mean this? `<ion-card *ngIf="oefening1" (click)="test(oefening1)">` and `click(value) { console.log(value); }`

Comment: the value of that variable `oefening1` so whats iside {{ oefening1 }}?

When I do it like this: `
      <ion-card-title #oefening1>{{ oefening1 }}</ion-card-title>`
` <ion-card *ngIf="oefening1" (click)="test($event, oefening1)">`

The card title is [object HTMLElement]

Comment: don't pass `$event` just pass `oefening1` You don't need the click target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating things - just pass the identifier of the page into your `navigate` method - i.e. the method that is triggered on clicking the card.

So, your template:

```
<ion-card *ngIf="oefening1" (click)="navigate('oefening1')" id="lagerugklacht" class="lagerugklacht">
  <img src="assets/img/lagerugklacht.jpg"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>{{ oefening1 }}</ion-card-title>
    <p>Setjes: {{ set1 }}</p>
    <p>Herhalingen: {{ rep1 }}</p>
  </ion-card-content> 
</ion-card>
```

And in your component:

```
navigate(card: string){
  this.navCtrl.push(ExercisePage, {
    card: card
  });
}
```

Then in your ExercisePage component, you can pull out the `card` using `NavParams`

In ExerciseComponent:

```
class ExerciseComponent {
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     ....
     let card = navParams.get('card');
     // have fun with card value here
     ....
  }
}
```